# Alter Trace (SQL Server Profiler) security risks?

Tags: sql-server, profiler, trace

SQL Server database -- a read only node specifically (not exactly sure how that works).

Our database keeps crashing due to memory issues - various error messages indicate this. It's hard to tell if it's various user queries, or other background processes.

Our team does not administer said database. But -- as you might intuit, there are no strong resources (re: anybody) that really is dba'ing the database effectively.

It seems using the SQL Server Profiler (alter trace) is almost, if not actually, at the sys-admin level of privileges, which the actual sys-admins are reluctant to grant.

Is there a way to grant alter-trace without sys-admin-level security risks?

Comment: Is your end goal to be able to run the Profiler to monitor what queries are running on the server?

Comment: Hmm. Well I guess the idea is to diagnose and prevent crashes of the server. Either there is abnormal behavior happening on the server (not blame game stuff, maybe errant backup processes or something) --- OR -- the server hardware provisioning is anemic and not sufficient for the queries being placed on it. Without visibility or a dedicated DBA really, it's hard to figure out the best potential path forward.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and add the exact error messages?

Comment: I guess my point is you shouldn't need to `ALTER TRACE` to be able to run the Profiler. I don't even think you need `SysAdmin` privileges either (though I'd have to check). Also, agreed with vonPryz, you're better off posting details on the exact errors you're getting and we should be able to help diagnose. Your database shouldn't be *crashing* with pegged Memory per se, just slow and potentially timing out if your application specifies a query execution timeout.

Comment: You should use an XEvent session instead. You need `VIEW SERVER STATE` to view the results and `ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION` to create or change one. Not too terrible.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you need ALTER TRACE to use the old trace engine, but ir from Profiler or using the stored procedures (etc) directly. As already suggested, consider using Extended Events instead. Among other things, XE haven't been dead since 2008.